# Rails saving relations even having validation errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5, has-and-belongs-to-many

I have Many-to-Many relation between two models using Has And Belongs To Many. The relation is between `Post` and `Site`. This relation is defined by checkboxes on form using `site_ids` param.

The problem is when I update a `Post` form having validation errors, the relation is saved even with validation errors.

I also tried set autosave false for HABTM.

My `Post` model:

```
class Post
  has_and_belongs_to_many :sites, join_table: "posts_sites"

  validates_presence_of :title
end
```

When I send new relations IDs but without a title for example, Post is not saved, but relation is created and it's not rolled back.

```
> p = Post.last
> p.sites.map(&:id)
=> [1]

> p.update_attributes(site_ids: [1,2], title: '')

(0.2ms)  BEGIN

Site Load (0.4ms)  SELECT `sites`.* FROM `sites` WHERE `sites`.`id` IN (1, 2)

SQL (1.3ms)  INSERT INTO `posts_sites` (`site_id`, `post_id`, `created_at`, `updated_at`) VALUES (2, 3, '2017-08-07 21:28:00', '2017-08-07 21:28:00')
(5.7ms)  COMMIT
(0.2ms)  BEGIN

(0.5ms)  ROLLBACK
=> false

> p.errors.messages
=> {:title=>["can not be blank"]}

> Post.last.sites.map(&:id)
=> [1, 2]
```

How can I rollback relations when I get validation errors?

Comment: Your log indicates that the insertion into `posts_sites` is rolled back.

Comment: @DavidAldridge The rollback went to `post` not `posts_sites`. You can see it at the end of log, I search for IDs and it was saved.

Comment: Do you mean these two tables belong to two different databases?

Comment: @VijayAgrawal Is the same database, but 3 tables: `posts`, `sites` and `posts_sites`.

Comment: A `rollback` reverts changes done to all the tables in that transaction

Comment: We also can't see all the generated SQL there.

Comment: @VijayAgrawal On rails console it works, but on ActiveAdmin, commit is called and then a new begin is called. I read about gem `deferred_associations` which fixes this problem, but it is not compatible with Rails 5.